# I do not want my function to return null. What is the best solution?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
    public <T extends BasePage> T clickSubMenuItem(MenuBar menuBar) {
    int hoveredMenuItemIndex =mouseOverToMenuItemByTitle(menuBar.menuOptionTitle);
    if (hoveredMenuItemIndex > -1) 
    {
     allSubMenuItem = getWebElements(By.cssSelector("#topnav > .rootmenu > li:nth-child(" + hoveredMenuItemIndex + ") > ul > li > a"));
        for (WebElement subMenuItem : allSubMenuItem) {
            if (subMenuItem.getAttribute("title").contains(menuBar.subMenuTitle)) {
                subMenuItem.click();
                return instantiatePageClass((Class<T>) menuBar.expectedPageClass);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

**This function returns a class, but if the menu item is not clicked it should not return anything and fail. I do not want to use null and i am not allowed to use a try catch block**

Comment: Return an empty object

Comment: Throw a `ClassNotFoundException`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 8, change return type to [`Optional<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), then return [`Optional.of(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#of-T-) or [`Optional.empty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty--).

The caller can then call [`returnValue.isPresent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent--), and if true can call [`returnValue.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--) to get the actual value. Check the javadoc for other useful methods.

```
public <T extends BasePage> Optional<T> clickSubMenuItem(MenuBar menuBar) {
    int hoveredMenuItemIndex =mouseOverToMenuItemByTitle(menuBar.menuOptionTitle);
    if (hoveredMenuItemIndex > -1) {
        allSubMenuItem = getWebElements(By.cssSelector("#topnav > .rootmenu > li:nth-child(" + hoveredMenuItemIndex + ") > ul > li > a"));
        for (WebElement subMenuItem : allSubMenuItem) {
            if (subMenuItem.getAttribute("title").contains(menuBar.subMenuTitle)) {
                subMenuItem.click();
                return Optional.of(instantiatePageClass((Class<T>) menuBar.expectedPageClass));
            }
        }
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Return Optional and take an action to it.

Example :

```
Optional<T extends Page> myMethod(){
    //logic
    return Optional.empty();
}

myMethod.map(someClass::someAction).orElse(doWhatEverYouWantWhenNull);
```

For more information about optional : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html